# Is tab-switching a feature in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

By this I mean if some file was written with 4 spaces, can you simply highlight it all and click on something to turn it into 2 spaces. I'm not sure if in practice (parsing) this would make sense/could lead to broken code.

I currently have my editor.tabSize set to 2, and sometimes I open files written with 4 spaces and I want to be able to turn them into 2 spaces. I have at least figured out to turn off the auto-detect so that when I highlight sections of the code and hit shift-tab, then tab again it will turn the selected code from 4 spaces into 2 spaces.

Is there a feature like this or does it make sense that this wouldn't exist?

Comment: You have option at bottom right corner. Set the desired intendation and format document

Comment: I tried it, didn't work. What do you mean by format the document? Do I need to highlight the text? I tried that, hit the bottom-right tabsize, window appears top of page, indent using spaces/tabs, click what I want, doesn't change the text. Maybe it's because I turned the automatic-tab detection off, aside from changing the bottom-right thing not sure if that's the problem.

Comment: @Matt Bierner has given the answer. In latest vscode versions, after choosing "indent using spaces/tabs" and its "size", you could simple right click on the file opened and choose "Format Document" from the right click menu

Comment: @bijin-ab thanks I see that your first answer was correct I didn't know the format document part, I saw it before but did not make the sequential-connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the current document from using 4 spaces to 2 spaces:

1. Click on `Spaces: 4` in the status bar or run the `Indent using Spaces` command
2. Select 2 for the new `tab size`
3. Run for `Format Document` command to apply the new indentation to the entire document

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the gif. bijin above was right I missed the format document part. Thanks, also I'm familiar with your work on GitHub regarding VSCode thanks.